# How to prevent race conditions when merging changes across threads?

Tags: multithreading, core-data, merge, race-condition

A typical setup: we have a main thread with a `mainMOC` and a background thread with its own `backgroundMOC`. The background thread performs read-only operations on the `backgroundMOC` by dispatching blocks to a `backgroundQueue`.

The `backgroundMOC` needs to merge the changes from the `mainMOC` so we register for `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` and then do something like

```
- (void)mainMocDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification {
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
        [backgroundMoc mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
    });
}
```

Let's say the user deletes an object in the `mainMOC`. The code above does not seem safe to me, since the merge will be done at some point in the future. Until the merge is done, there might still be blocks on the `backgroundQueue` that are trying to use the deleted object.

The obvious solution would be to use `dispatch_sync` instead (or `performBlockAndWait`, `performSelector:OnThread:...`) instead. From the code snippets I see on the interwebs, this seems to be what everybody is doing. But I'm not comfortable with this solution either.

The name `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` implies that the save has already happened when the notification is delivered. So the corresponding row has already been deleted from the underlying database (assuming an sqlite store). `dispatch_sync` will have to wait for other blocks on the queue to finish before it can merge the changes, and these other blocks could still try to work with the deleted object, leading to an `NSObjectInaccessibleException`.

It seems to me that the correct way to merge changes from one thread/queue to another would be to

1. Subscribe to `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification` and `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` on the background thread.
2. On `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification`: empty the `backgroundQueue` and suspend any operations that dispatch new blocks to the queue.
3. On `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`: merge the changes synchronously.
4. Resume normal operation on the background queue.

Is this the correct approach or am I missing something?

Comment: As a follow up: I keep getting deadlocks with the solution above. It seems that in some cases the lock on the PSC has already been acquired by the main thread when it sends `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification` which can cause the dispatch_sync call required in step 2 above to wait forever when there's still an unfinished task on the background queue.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following structure in two projects in which I experienced similar troubles as you did. First of all I use singleton service to ensure there is only one background thread merging and reading changes.

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        // It is crucial to use the correct concurrency type!
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

- (void)saveContext {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
             // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
             // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
        else {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ParentContextDidSaveNotification" object:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

**BackgroundService.m**

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        [self managedObjectContext];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(parentContextDidSave) name:@"ParentContextDidSaveNotification" object:nil];
    }

    return self;
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    if (!_managedObjectContext) {
        // Again, make sure you use the correct concurrency type!
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        [_managedObjectContext setParentContext:[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]];
    }

    return _managedObjectContext;
}


- (BOOL)saveContext {
    @synchronized(self) {
        BOOL successful = YES;

        // Bad practice, process errors appropriately.
        [[self managedObjectContext] save:nil];

        [[[self managedObjectContext] parentContext] performBlock:^{
            [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] saveContext];
        }];

        return successful;
    }
}

- (void)parentContextDidSave {
    [[self managedObjectContext] reset];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ManagedObjectContextResetNotification" object:nil];
}
```